# JAXB - Multiple values to the same element

Tags: java, binding, jaxb

My use case is something like this, I get an object with multiple properties which I need to map to 2 elements in my XML using Jaxb.

Eg:
 Employee Object has emp id, emp name, salary

This need to be mapped to

```
<customProperties> 
<customPropName> EmpId </customPropName>
<customPropId> 123456 </customPropId>
<customPropName> EmpName </customPropName>
<customPropId> John Doe </customPropId>
<customPropName> Salary </customPropName>
<customPropId> 1029 </customPropId>
<customProperties>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You should post the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jonathan, however being new to this. I dont even know where to start. I am not looking at complete code but some pointers to point me in the right direction.